# Reading really big blobs without downloading them in Google Cloud (streaming?)

Tags: python, stream, google-cloud-platform, prefetch

please help!

**[+] What I have:** 
A lot of blobs in every bucket. Blobs can vary in size from being less than a Kilo-byte to being lots of Giga-bytes.

**[+] What I'm trying to do:**
I need to be able to either stream the data in those blobs (like a buffer of size 1024 or something like that) or read them by chunks of a certain size in Python. The point is I don't think I can just do a bucket.get_blob() because if the blob was a TeraByte then I wouldn't be able to have it in physical memory.

**[+] What I'm really trying to do:** 
parse the information inside the blobs to identify key-words

**[+] What I've read:**
A lot of documentation on how to write to google cloud in chunks and then use compose to stitch it together (not helpful at all)

A lot of documentation on java's pre-fetch functions (needs to be python)

The google cloud API's

If anyone could point me the right direction I would be really grateful! 
Thanks

Comment: I am trying to figure this out myself. If you have figured this out, can you share your solution to save me some time?

Answer (score 4):

So a way I have found of doing this is by creating a file-like object in python then using the Google-Cloud API call .download_to_file() with that file-like object.

This in essence streams data. 
python code looks something like this

```
def getStream(blob):
    stream = open('myStream','wb', os.O_NONBLOCK)
    streaming = blob.download_to_file(stream)
```

The os.O_NONBLOCK flag is so I can read while I'm writing to the file. 
I still haven't tested this with really big files so if anyone knows a better implementation or see's a potential failure with this please comment. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think you found the right method. Check here [the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/d4d0abcab27b3f1aba9b56db4d643d5692230bd5/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L293) for further insight.