# How to open a file from google cloud storage into a cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

Here is how I normally download a GCS file to local:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myBigFile.txt')
blob.download_to_filename('myBigFile.txt)
```

The files that I am working with a much, much larger than the allowable size/memory of the Cloud Functions (for example, several GBs to several TBs), so the above would not work for these large files.

Is there a simpler, "streaming" (see example 1 below) or "direct-access" (see example 2 below) way to work with GCS files in a Cloud Function?

Two examples of what I'd be looking to do would be:

```
# 1. Load it in chunks of 5GB -- "Streaming"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myBigFile.txt')
while True:
    data = blob.download_to_filename('myBigFile.txt', chunk_size=5GB)
    do_something(data)
    if not data: break
```

Or:

```
# 2. Read the data from GCS without downloading it locally -- "Direct Access"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myBigFile.txt')
with blob.read_filename('myBigFile.txt') as f:
    do_something(f)
```

I'm not sure if either of these are possible to do, but I'm leaving a few options of how this could work. It seems like the [Streaming Option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) is supported, but I wasn't sure how to apply it to the above case.

Comment: Could you comment on how you plan to use the data contained in the cloud storage bucket objects within your function?  Perhaps if we knew how the data was used we could offer better guidance?

Comment: @Kolban I just updated the question with a couple of examples. I'm saving the data to either a new filetype (such as avro) or inserting it into a database.

Comment: Might this be what you want?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380237/reading-really-big-blobs-without-downloading-them-in-google-cloud-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to achieve something close to your #1 example using the [Cloud Storage XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview).

There *should* not be a problem implementing it inside Cloud Functions since it's entirely based on standard HTTP requests.

You're probably looking for the [GET Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object) request to [Download an Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download):

> GET requests for objects can include a Range header as defined in the
> HTTP 1.1 RFC to limit the scope of the returned data within the
> object, but be aware that in [certain circumstances](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#range) the range
> header is ignored.

That HTTP [Range](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#range) header appear to be usable to implement the "chunks" you're looking for (but as standalone requests, not in a "streaming" mode):

> The range of bytes that you want returned in the response, or the
> range of bytes that have been uploaded to the Cloud Storage system.
>
> **Valid Values**
>
> Any contiguous range of bytes.
>
> **Example**
>
> `Range: bytes=0-1999` (first 2000 bytes)
>
> `Range: bytes=-2000` (last 2000 bytes)
>
> `Range: bytes=2000-` (from byte 2000 to end of file)
>
> **Implementation Details**
>
> Cloud Storage does not handle complex disjoint ranges, but it does
> support simple contiguous byte ranges. Also, byte ranges are
> inclusive; that is, bytes=0-999 represent the first 1000 bytes in a
> file or object. A valid and successful request will result in a [206
> Partial Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) response code. For more information, see the
> [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.1).

Since the ranges would be static it's unlikely you'll be able to find range values exactly fit to make the chunks perfectly match the stored data "borders". So you may need to choose the chunks overlapping a bit, to be able to capture data which otherwise would be split across 2 chunks.

Note: I didn't try this, the answer is based solely on docs.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, the standard Google Cloud Client library does not support stream-like up-/download.

Have a look at [GCSFS](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Caveat, you may need to implement a retry strategy in case connection gets lost.

Comment: With your answer, I could find my way through the jungle! Wrote the story down at [When writing csv from CF to bucket: 'with open(filepath, "w") as MY_CSV:' leads to "FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory:"](https://serverfault.com/questions/1091789/when-writing-csv-from-cf-to-bucket-with-openfilepath-w-as-my-csv-leads/1091865#1091865).