# How to stream data line by line from bucket to python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on large data files stored in Google Cloud. I'm using a Python script which downloads first a blob containing json lines, and then opens it to analyze data line by line. This method is very slow, and i'd like to know if exists a faster way to do this. From command line i can use `gsutil cat` to stream data to stdout, is there a similar way to do this on Python?

This is what i currently do to read data:

```
myClient = storage.Client()
bucket = myClient.get_bucket(bucketname)
blob = storage.blob.Blob(blobname, bucket)
current_blob.download_to_filename("filename.txt")

file = open("filename.txt", "r")
data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    # Do stuff
```

I want to read the blob line by line, without waiting for download.

Edit: i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380237/reading-really-big-blobs-without-downloading-them-in-google-cloud-streaming) but the function isn't clear to me. I don't know how to read the streaming lines.

Answer (score 0):

In the [answer you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380237/reading-really-big-blobs-without-downloading-them-in-google-cloud-streaming), `stream` is a file-like object, so you should be able to use it instead of opening a specific filename. Something like this (untested):

```
myClient = storage.Client()
bucket = myClient.get_bucket(bucketname)
blob = storage.blob.Blob(blobname, bucket)
stream = open('myStream','wb', os.O_NONBLOCK)
streaming = blob.download_to_file(stream)

for line in stream.readlines():
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: I tried that, it gives me the error `for line in stream.readlines():
io.UnsupportedOperation: read` . How can i make the object readable?

Comment: Opening the file as `wb` won't create the file if it doesn't exist already. Additionally, the file is not readable and `stream.readlines()` will fail with the error @alcor mentioned. The solution is to use `a+b` (open in read+write mode and create if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't result in processing the file in a stream-like way (as written) - `stream.readlines()` is starting at the end of the file, so doesn't yield any lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BlobReader](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobReader).

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket(bucketname)
blob = bucket.blob(blobname)
reader = storage.fileio.BlobReader(blob)

for line in reader:
    # Do stuff with each line
```